# CakePHP 3: SQL exception with left join issue

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have 4 tables (ApplicationsGroupsServersTable, ApplicationsTable, ServersTable, GroupsTable). I am trying to use left join in CakePHP with below code, but I get below SQL exception:

`Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Group ON Group.id = ApplicationsGroupsServers.group_id' at line 1`

Here is the code I have it in ApplicationsGroupsServersController:

```
$option =array(
    'fields' => array(
      'Server.server_name',
        'Group.group_name'
    ),
    'join' => array(
       array(
                'table' => 'Servers',
                'alias' => 'Server',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array( 'Server.id = ApplicationsGroupsServers.server_id' )
            ),
        array (
            'table' => 'Groups',
            'alias' => 'Group',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array( 'Group.id = ApplicationsGroupsServers.group_id' )
        )
    )
);
$apps = $this->ApplicationsGroupsServers->find('all', $option);
$this->set('applications', $apps);
```

Here is the associations I have:

ApplicationsGroupsServersTable:

```
$this->belongsTo('Applications', [
    'foreignKey' => 'application_id'
]);
$this->belongsTo('Groups', [
    'foreignKey' => 'group_id'
]);
$this->belongsTo('Servers', [
    'foreignKey' => 'server_id'
]);
```

ApplicationsTable:

```
$this->hasMany('ApplicationsGroupsServers', [
   'foreignKey' => 'application_id'
]);
```

GroupsTable:

```
$this->hasMany('ApplicationsGroupsServers', [
    'foreignKey' => 'group_id'
]);
```

I thought my associates were not setup correctly, but when I run left join with one table, I am table to get the data. Here is the code below that works:

```
        $option =array(
            'fields' => array(
              'Server.server_name',
                // 'Group.group_name'
            ),
            'join' => array(
               array(
                        'table' => 'Servers',
                        'alias' => 'Server',
                        'type' => 'LEFT',
                        'conditions' => array( 'Server.id = ApplicationsGroupsServers.server_id' )
                    )
//                array (
//                    'table' => 'Groups',
//                    'alias' => 'Group',
//                    'type' => 'LEFT',
//                    'conditions' => array( 'Group.id = ApplicationsGroupsServers.group_id' )
//                )
            )
        );
        $apps = $this->ApplicationsGroupsServers->find('all', $option);
        $this->set('applications', $apps);
```

Comment: `GROUP` is a reserved word in MySQL and probably other dialects as well. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html I wouldn't use it this way in any case.

Comment: Thank you burzum. I changed my query `'Group.group_name'` as `'g.group_name'` and `array (
                    'table' => 'Groups',
                    'alias' => 'g',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                  'conditions' => array( 'Group.id = ApplicationsGroupsServers.group_id' )
               )`

and it worked :)